# Access python web application from internet

Tags: linux, webserver, port, eve

I am running an Eve instance on my Linux webserver to allow me to access a database using HTTP.  When I run the script, the following is displayed:

`* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`

`lsof -i :5000` yields

`COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
python  11824 root    3u  IPv4 10213572      0t0  TCP localhost:5000 (LISTEN)`

Trying to access http://goodenough.io:5000 doesn't work. I have this working on localhost on my Windows, but it just won't work over the internet.

http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ shows that the port is closed despite the app listening and Digital Ocean claiming all ports are open by default.

But my new theory is that perhaps there is more to having external requests recognized?

Any ideas or suggestions would be amazing.  Thank you.

Comment: It says running on `localhost`, the server's internal loopback interface - i.e.  not accessible over the network. Update your Eve configuration to listen on the external IP interface(s).

Comment: This is awesome!  How do I do this?? @isedev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application, there must be some code like this:

```
app = Eve()
app.run()
```

This will listen on the loopback interface by default. To listen on a specific IP address (the externally visible IP in your case), use:

```
app.run(host="X.X.X.X")
```

where X.X.X.X is the relevant IP.

Comment: This was 100% the answer.  It runs wonderfully now!  I've only ever got this working on my local machine and now I know why...